# Tensor Flow all predictions are 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, prediction

I'm running the following code for TensorFlow and all the probabilities are `NaN` and all the predictions are `0`. The accuracy works, however. I have no idea how to debug this. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 22])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([22, 5]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W))
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
#cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf_softmax_correct*tf.log(tf_softmax  + 1e-50))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(100):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = random.sample(allTrainingArray,100), random.sample(allTrainingSkillsArray,100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

#test on itself
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print "accuracy", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

probabilities = y
print "probabilities", probabilities.eval(feed_dict={x: allTrainingArray}, session=sess)

prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
print "predictions", prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: allTrainingArray}, session = sess)
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue stems from this line in your code:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([22, 5]))
```

Initializing your weights to zero is a common mistake when defining a neural network. [This article](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init) explains the reasoning behind it (very approximately, all the neurons will have the same value, so the network won't learn). Instead you should initialize your weights to small random numbers, and a typical scheme is to use [`tf.truncated_normal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#truncated_normal) with a standard deviation inversely proporational to the number of input units:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([22, 5], stddev=1./22.))
```

[rrao's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036025/3574081) to add a bias term, and switch to the more numerically stable [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) op for your loss function are good ideas as well, and these will probably be necessary steps to get reasonable accuracy.

Comment: @rrao I incorporated both of your suggestions, and still no luck :/ I did some debugging and it seems that after my training step, the weights are all NaN, which messes up the future calculations. Do you have any idea what could be causing the weights to turn into NaN after running the training step?

Comment: first thing I tried :/ no luck. I have no idea what this is. Could it be the data? What I have is 283 rows of players with 22 different attributes in allTrainingArray, and matching that is 283 players with [0,0,0,0,1] (or 1 in any of those locations), indicating what kind of player he is. I looked at the TF example to make my data arrays so I didn't think it would be a problem.

Comment: @ShyamKotak, would help a lot if you could give a sample of your row and labels,otherwise mrry answer seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue calculating your loss. It may also help your results if you add a `biases` vector.

You should try this:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([22, 5])) # can try better initialization methods
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5])) # can try better initialization methods
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(
   tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_)
)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

In case you want to look into [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)